# why do i get no response in "form.submit()" inside xhr.onreadystatechange() in javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

`form.submit()` function doesn't work in response with `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

This is my login form:

```
<form action="user_home.php" method="post" id="loginForm" >
   <tr>
     <td colspan=2>Members log in here:</td>
   <tr>
     <td>Username:</td>
     <td><input type='text' name='username' id='username' /></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type='password' name='password' id="password" /></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan=2 align='center'>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value= "Login" /></td></tr>
</form>
<script src="forLogin.js"></script>
```

in javascript

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || (xhr.status == 304)) {
      if (xhr.responseText == 'VALID') {

        alert(xhr.responseText); //this works

        var form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        form.submit(); // it doesnt work!!!
      } else {
        var message = '<h2>Error!</h2><p>The following Error(s) occured: <ul>';
        message += '<li class="error">Invalid Username Password combinations!</li>';
        showErrorMessage(message);
      }
      xhr = null;
    }
  }
};
```

When my ajax function send->  **echo 'VALID';**
I get an alert but doesn't get redirection. Why?
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: When is your ajax call executed? Is it on the form submit?

Comment: Where do you do the XHR request? How is that triggered?

Comment: i have given only a portion of my code, where i know the code occurs. but why do people make my questions -ve response!!  see my answer, when i changed "name" and "id" fields in html tags, i got correct answer.  Any one who make this type of error can be help full this ...then too -ve mark:-@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was here,

```
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' /> 
 <input type='password' name='password' id="password" />
```

change it to:-

```
    <td><input name='username' id='username'  type='text'  >
   <td><input name='password' id="password" type='password'  >
```

now works...

Comment: I just see that you change the order of the attributes and removed the `/` at the end, but IMHO this can't be the reason for the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You could try

```
   document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();
```

instead of

```
                var form = document.getElementById('loginForm');

                form.submit();// it doesnt work!!!
```

Comment: Why should this make any difference?

Comment: same result...no navigation